# webpack fail to build, suddently get: Critical dependency, Can't resolve, Invalid dependencies and more

Tags: webpack, electron, windows-10, electron-forge

My webpackwith [`electron forge`](https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack) was fine, I ran `yarn make` the command has been successful. I was trying to make icpRender work (through preloader script) when "suddenly" the webpack did stop working and I get tons of errors that, I'd say totally unrelated to what I was working on. What possibly could be the reason? I see something broken in the dependencies but I have no idea why. How do I fix that? I'm pretty sure adding dependencies manually isn't the proper way to do that rather I should focus on the root issue.

I can past only part of the error message due to stackoverflow's body message limit. So the full error is [`here`](https://pastebin.com/tfCDHe71)

the error:

> > An unhandled error has occurred inside Forge: Compilation errors in the main process: assets by status 123 MiB [cached] 87 assets runtime
> > modules 898 bytes 5 modules orphan modules 3.29 KiB [orphan] 4 modules
> > javascript modules 6.21 MiB   cacheable modules 6.21 MiB 1162 modules
>
> - 29 modules json modules 667 KiB   modules by path ./node_modules/dmg-builder/ 86.7 KiB 8 modules   modules by path
>   ./node_modules/@babel/ 32.8 KiB 5 modules   modules by path
>   ./node_modules/core-js-compat/*.json 334 KiB 4 modules   modules by
>   path ./node_modules/ajv/lib/ 3.12 KiB 2 modules   modules by path
>   ./node_modules/node-releases/data/ 20.1 KiB
>   ./node_modules/node-releases/data/processed/envs.json 18.6 KiB [built] [code generated]
>   ./node_modules/node-releases/data/release-schedule/release-schedule.json
>   1.54 KiB [built] [code generated]   + 9 modules

[...]

> 15 warnings have detailed information that is not shown. Use
> 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/ProtonFramework.js 72:8-63
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind' in
> 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\merge\Newton\node_modules\app-builder-lib\out'
> @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 19:26-54  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/ProtonFramework.js 74:8-69
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from' in
> 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\merge\Newton\node_modules\app-builder-lib\out'
> @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 19:26-54  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/ProtonFramework.js 77:9-68
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator' in
> 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\merge\Newton\node_modules\app-builder-lib\out'
> @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 19:26-54  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/ProtonFramework.js 79:8-64
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions' in
> 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\merge\Newton\node_modules\app-builder-lib\out'
> @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 19:26-54  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/ProtonFramework.js 82:8-63
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent' in
> 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\merge\Newton\node_modules\app-builder-lib\out'
> @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 19:26-54  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/ProtonFramework.js 85:8-67
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions' in
> 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\merge\Newton\node_modules\app-builder-lib\out'
> @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 19:26-54  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/ProtonFramework.js 88:8-59
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta' in
> 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\merge\Newton\node_modules\app-builder-lib\out'
> @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 19:26-54  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/dmg-builder/out/dmgLicense.js 9:22-44 Module
> not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dmg-license' in
> 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\merge\Newton\node_modules\dmg-builder\out'  @
> ./node_modules/dmg-builder/out/dmg.js 13:21-44  @
> ./node_modules/dmg-builder/out/dmgUtil.js 7:12-28  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/macPackager.js 63:42-64  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 377:72-96  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/read-config-file/out/main.js 25:17-38 Module
> not found: Error: Can't resolve 'toml' in
> 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\merge\Newton\node_modules\read-config-file\out'
> @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/util/config.js 9:27-54  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 21:17-41  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> 9 errors have detailed information that is not shown. Use
> 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.
>
> webpack 5.67.0 compiled with 9 errors and 15 warnings in 83110 ms
> Error: Compilation errors in the main process: assets by status 123
> MiB [cached] 87 assets runtime modules 898 bytes 5 modules orphan
> modules 3.29 KiB [orphan] 4 modules javascript modules 6.21 MiB
> cacheable modules 6.21 MiB 1162 modules   + 29 modules json modules
> 667 KiB   modules by path ./node_modules/dmg-builder/ 86.7 KiB 8
> modules   modules by path ./node_modules/@babel/ 32.8 KiB 5 modules
> modules by path ./node_modules/core-js-compat/*.json 334 KiB 4 modules
> modules by path ./node_modules/ajv/lib/ 3.12 KiB 2 modules   modules
> by path ./node_modules/node-releases/data/ 20.1 KiB
> ./node_modules/node-releases/data/processed/envs.json 18.6 KiB [built] [code generated]
> ./node_modules/node-releases/data/release-schedule/release-schedule.json
> 1.54 KiB [built] [code generated]   + 9 modules
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/import.js
> 9:9-25 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
> expression  @
> ./node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js 48:12-39
> @ ./node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
> 69:19-44  @ ./node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
> 64:21-47  @ ./node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js 189:13-38  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/ProtonFramework.js 32:20-42  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 19:26-54  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/app-builder-bin/index.js Invalid
> dependencies have been reported by plugins or loaders for this module.
> All reported dependencies need to be absolute paths. Invalid
> dependencies may lead to broken watching and caching. As best effort
> we try to convert all invalid values to absolute paths and converting
> globs into context dependencies, but this is deprecated behavior.
> Loaders: Pass absolute paths to this.addDependency (existing files),
> this.addMissingDependency (not existing files), and
> this.addContextDependency (directories). Plugins: Pass absolute paths
> to fileDependencies (existing files), missingDependencies (not
> existing files), and contextDependencies (directories). Globs: They
> are not supported. Pass absolute path to the directory as context
> dependencies. The following invalid values have been reported:  *
> "C:/Users/jack/Desktop/merge/Newton/node_modules/app-builder-bin/linux/arm/app-builder"
>
> - "C:/Users/jack/Desktop/merge/Newton/node_modules/app-builder-bin/linux/arm64/app-builder"
> - "C:/Users/jack/Desktop/merge/Newton/node_modules/app-builder-bin/linux/ia32/app-builder"
> - and more ...  @ ./node_modules/builder-util/out/util.js 5:26-52  @ ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 4:21-44  @
>   ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/ProtonFramework.js
> 38:24-45 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-core' in
> 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\merge\Newton\node_modules\app-builder-lib\out'
> @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 19:26-54  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/util/pathManager.js
> Invalid dependencies have been reported by plugins or loaders for this
> module. All reported dependencies need to be absolute paths. Invalid
> dependencies may lead to broken watching and caching. As best effort
> we try to convert all invalid values to absolute paths and converting
> globs into context dependencies, but this is deprecated behavior.
> Loaders: Pass absolute paths to this.addDependency (existing files),
> this.addMissingDependency (not existing files), and
> this.addContextDependency (directories). Plugins: Pass absolute paths
> to fileDependencies (existing files), missingDependencies (not
> existing files), and contextDependencies (directories). Globs: They
> are not supported. Pass absolute path to the directory as context
> dependencies. The following invalid values have been reported:  *
> "C:/Users/jack/Desktop/merge/Newton/node_modules/app-builder-lib/templates/appx/appxmanifest.xml"
>
> - "C:/Users/jack/Desktop/merge/Newton/node_modules/app-builder-lib/templates/appx/priconfig.xml"
> - "C:/Users/jack/Desktop/merge/Newton/node_modules/app-builder-lib/templates/entitlements.mac.plist"
> - and more ...  @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/ProtonFramework.js 9:22-51  @
>   ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 19:26-54  @
>   ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
>   ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
>   ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/winPackager.js 146:39-91
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> 'electron-builder-squirrel-windows' in
> 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\merge\Newton\node_modules\app-builder-lib\out'
> @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 381:72-96  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/browserslist/node.js 171:42-49 Critical
> dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies
> cannot be statically extracted  @ ./node_modules/browserslist/index.js
> 8:10-27  @
> ./node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib/index.js 45:20-43
> @ ./node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js 38:32-76  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/ProtonFramework.js 69:29-65  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 19:26-54  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/browserslist/node.js 192:40-47 Critical
> dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies
> cannot be statically extracted  @ ./node_modules/browserslist/index.js
> 8:10-27  @
> ./node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib/index.js 45:20-43
> @ ./node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js 38:32-76  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/ProtonFramework.js 69:29-65  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 19:26-54  @
> ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
> ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
> ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/dmg-builder/out/dmgUtil.js Invalid
> dependencies have been reported by plugins or loaders for this module.
> All reported dependencies need to be absolute paths. Invalid
> dependencies may lead to broken watching and caching. As best effort
> we try to convert all invalid values to absolute paths and converting
> globs into context dependencies, but this is deprecated behavior.
> Loaders: Pass absolute paths to this.addDependency (existing files),
> this.addMissingDependency (not existing files), and
> this.addContextDependency (directories). Plugins: Pass absolute paths
> to fileDependencies (existing files), missingDependencies (not
> existing files), and contextDependencies (directories). Globs: They
> are not supported. Pass absolute path to the directory as context
> dependencies. The following invalid values have been reported:  *
> "C:/Users/jack/Desktop/merge/Newton/node_modules/dmg-builder/templates/background.tiff"
>
> - "C:/Users/jack/Desktop/merge/Newton/node_modules/dmg-builder/vendor/biplist/**init**.py"
> - "C:/Users/jack/Desktop/merge/Newton/node_modules/dmg-builder/vendor/dmgbuild/badge.py"
> - and more ...  @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/macPackager.js 63:42-64  @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/packager.js 377:72-96
>   @ ./node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/index.js 7:19-40 10:17-38  @
>   ./node_modules/electron-builder/out/index.js 11:24-50 19:24-50  @
>   ./public/electron.js 4:20-47
>   15 warnings have detailed information that is not shown. Use
>   'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.
>   [...]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ed",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "ed",
  "author": {
    "name": "jack",
    "email": "foo@baa.com"
  },
  "private": true,
  "main": ".webpack/main",
  "homepage": "./",
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "ed"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          {
            "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
            "renderer": {
              "nodeIntegration": true,
              "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
              "entryPoints": [
                {
                  "html": "./public/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/index.js",
                  "name": "main_window",
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./src/preload.js"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-web-ui-property-grid": "^1.1.1",
    "common-js": "^0.3.8",
    "commonjs": "^0.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "history": "^5.0.1",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "npm": "^7.24.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.4",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-tabs": "^3.2.2",
    "react-tinder-card": "^1.4.5",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3004 && react-scripts start",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "dist": "yarn run build && electron-builder build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start\" \"npm:electron\"",
    "electron": "wait-on tcp:3004 && electron ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack": "6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader": "1.7.0",
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "electron": "^16.0.6",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.5",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-packager": "^15.4.0",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe node.js version has changed recently at your machine? Install NVM and switch to old version then.

Sometimes removal of **node_modules** and re-doing **npm install** helps.

Comment: I've tried both, downgrade and update the node version to least and I got the very same error. I've tried delete the mode_modules folder, reinstall the pakages and no luck